# loading texture from folder

Tags: java, textures, embedded-resource, jogl, application-resource

I'm having a problem loading a JPEG onto a sphere. Currently, the only way I have gotten this to work is to have the image in the same package as the class loading it. The problem is, I don't want to have 500+ textures all under one package mixed with classes. I would rather have them in folders and sub-folders for organizational reasons.

If the texture is in the same package, this works:

```
InputStream iStream = null;

    try
    {
        iStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(imageFile);
        TextureData data = TextureIO.newTextureData(iStream, false, null);
        testTex[i] = TextureIO.newTexture(data);
        testTex[i].getImageTexCoords();
        testTex[i].setTexParameteri(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL2.GL_LINEAR);
        testTex[i].setTexParameteri(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL2.GL_NEAREST);
        iStream.close();
        ...
```

The method that takes an image takes it in the form of:

```
String[] texture = { "bar1.jpg", "bar2.jpg" }; // imageFile is whichever is called
```

As the above code works perfectly, again, **the drawback is that every texture will have to be stored within the same package as the class that is calling for the texture.** But I want to call the texture like this from a folder within my project:

```
String[] texture = { "res/foo/bar2.jpg", "res/foo/bar2.jpg" };
```

How would I modify the above code to look for textures within a folder within the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// note leading '/' - indicates 'search from root of class-path'
String[] texture = { "/res/foo/bar2.jpg", "/res/foo/bar2.jpg" };
// ...
URL iUrl = getClass().getResource(texture[0]);
TextureData data = TextureIO.newTextureData(iUrl, false, "jpg");
```

In this example, we use an overloaded form of the `TextureIO` API loading method in [`newTextureData(URL,boolean,String)`](http://download.java.net/media/jogl/builds/archive/jsr-231-beta5/javadoc_public/com/sun/opengl/util/texture/TextureIO.html#newTextureData%28java.net.URL,%20boolean,%20java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is just that you're missing a slash before res. This will definitely work:

```
this.getClass().getResource("/res/img.jpg");
```

as long as the res package is in your src folder.